# MySQL Timeout in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on Microsoft Windows Server 2003. I have a PHP application in xampp/htdocs directory. I have started the Apache and MySQL instances.

I have noticed that every morning, my application gives a MySQL Error when I try to log in to my application. This is fixed after restarting MySQL instance in XAMPP control panel on the server. I think this may be due to timeout. How do I prevent timeout?

This is the my.ini:

```
[client] 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "D:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
plugin_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

skip-federated

server-id   = 1

innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

This is the error I come across every morning before restarting MySQL on XAMPP:

```
Warning: mysql_pconnect(): MySQL server has gone away in D:\MyApplication\mysql.inc on line 432

Warning: mysql_pconnect(): Link to server lost, unable to reconnect in D:\MyApplication\mysql.inc on line 432
Fatal Error: Failed to connect to database
```

Comment: maybe an infinite loop?

Comment: I think there is something to do with the configuration. Are you saying I should put a loop in my code?

Comment: no, what I am saying is ... without showing configuration, error and/or code is impossible to troubleshoot your issue

Comment: @LeaTano: I have added my.ini of MySQL. What other configuration files should I show? Or is this enough?

Comment: It always scares me when a question mentions "an error" and doesn't show the error...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Haha..I get it..I added the error info too..

Comment: If I recall correctly the relevant variable is [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) though you should check its runtime value (your *.ini file does not even change the 8-hour default value). Whatever, I'm not aware of any setting/feature that makes the whole MySQL Server hybernate or get iddle (it wouldn't be very useful). Is it possible that's the Windows server (or the hard disk or something) what's suspending?